# How to use grafana's plugin "Worldmap Panel" with zabbix?

Tags: zabbix, grafana

Is there a decision, how to use Grafana's [Worldmap](https://grafana.net/plugins/grafana-worldmap-panel) with zabbix 3.0.3?
I do not understand how to send geo information from servers to zabbix and from zabbix to grafana. I want to do something like [this](https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel) (on the first screenshot) - servers with errors on the map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://grafana.net/plugins/grafana-worldmap-panel says:

> World Map panel for Grafana. Displays time series data or geohash data
>   from Elasticsearch overlaid on a world map.

World Map plugin is not for Zabbix. It's only for data from **Elasticsearch**.

Zabbix provides maps - https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/visualisation/maps/map - use some nice map background and place your hosts into maps. Use different icons for different host problems states and result will be probably ok-awesome.

https://github.com/SpawW/zabbix-extras is project for Zabbix 2.2/2.4, which provides also Zabbix integration with Google Maps. It's not ported for Zabbix 3.0, but you can try.